# Регулярное выражение для разделения предложений

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо текст разбить на отдельные предложения используя регулярное выражение. Предложение начинается с заглавной буквы и заканчивается на ".!?"
Пробовал такое:

```
"\p{Upper}.*?[.!?](?=\s|$)"
```

Если текст написан в одном абзаце, то оно работает как надо. Однако с переносом строк как-то странно выходит.

Comment: \p{Upper}.*?[.!?](?=\s|$)

Comment: точка не всегда является указанием на конец предложения..... ! и ? тоже, но реже

Comment: Да с этим я успею еще подолбаться. Сейчас проблема только с переносами.

Comment: C какими переносами? откуда они берутся? из файла?

Comment: Да, весь текст - в файле изначально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вначале заменить в тексте все `\r\n|\r|\n` на `""`, а потом использовать **[BreakIterator](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/BreakIterator.html#KIND_SENTENCE)** для разделения на предложения. Возможно поможет.

Пример:

```
import java.text.BreakIterator;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        BreakIterator iterator = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance();
        String source = "Привет чувак! как дела? все нормально? да, хорошо, спасибо\r test \r\nпррр!\ntyty.";
        source = source.replaceAll("(\r\n|\r|\n)", "");
        iterator.setText(source);
        int start = iterator.first();
        for (int end = iterator.next();
             end != BreakIterator.DONE;
             start = end, end = iterator.next()) {
            System.out.println(source.substring(start,end));
        }
    }
}
```

выведет:

```
Привет чувак! 
как дела? 
все нормально? 
да, хорошо, спасибо test пррр!
tyty.
```

Comment: Я тут осознал, что моя ошибка заключалась совсем не в кривом регулярном выражении. В любом случае, спасибо за помощь!